# JButton setBackground doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, colors, background, jbutton

i try to set Background color of jbutton, but doesn't work? Look at image. Why doesnt work? How to fix?

I want red background :-)

[image]

```
    save_button.setForeground(Color.red);
    save_button.setBackground(Color.red);
    close_button.setForeground(Color.red);
    close_button.setBackground(Color.red);
```

Comment: Had you tried adding `save_button.setOpaque(true)` before setting `background/foreground` ? +1for the screenshot, though it will come in some time, my limit is gone for the day :-)

Comment: I tried and it's still the same :-)

Comment: May you please provide one [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), for us to test. Hope you not working with `Nimbus LookAndFeel` :-)

Comment: No, i am not working with nimbus look and feel

Comment: Works fine for me using JDK7 on Windows 7. Post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: ..Do you realize that if the foreground & background colors are the same, the text will be invisible?

Answer (score 1):

Add to the code for both buttons :

save_button.setOpaque(true);

It should work, if not try disabling the border color